# Delete RavenDB collection

Tags: ravendb, document-based

I need to delete a whole collection of documents in Raven DB. Deleting one by one (documents) is not a wise choice. Is there a way I can do this easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a set based operation.

[store.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex()](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/advanced/databasecommands/index) to do so

```cs
store.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(
    "Enquiries/MyEnquiryIndexName",
    new IndexQuery { Query = "Id:*", },
    allowStale: false);
```

[Code sample](https://gist.github.com/1868911) by @Marijin

Comment: Can we get an example? I'm spacing on this and just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about previous versions, but below applies to RavenDB 5.0

If you wanted to delete all documents from a collection called "Users", you could pass in the collection name to the [DeleteByQueryOperation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/operations/delete-by-query)

```cs
DeleteByQueryOperation("from Users")
```

A generic version would look something like this:

```cs
using Raven.Client.Documents;
using Raven.Client.Documents.Operations;

public class ExampleClass
{
  public static void DeleteCollection<TEntity>(IDocumentStore store, string databaseName)
  {
    var collectionName = store.Conventions.GetCollectionName(typeof(TEntity));

    store.Operations
      .ForDatabase(databaseName)
      .Send(new DeleteByQueryOperation($"from {collectionName}"));
  }
}
```